# Related records are insert every time

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have a table where articles and other tables are related to a table of images. Saving an image start calculating and saving the related thumbnails which is done in the model of the image (preSave). Saving an article start saving the images which starts the thumbnails process again. And I don't know why ...

When I save an article I only want to save the relation. Saving thumbnails is a hard process often causing a timeout and using too much resources.

How do I do that?

Here is a part of my schema reduced to the important aspects:

```
Image:
  columns:
    # ...
  relations:
    Flats:
      class: Flat
      refClass: FlatImage
      foreignAlias: Images
    Articles:
      class: Article
      refClass: ArticleImage
      foreignAlias: Articles

Thumbnail:
  columns:
    # ...
  relations:
    SourceImage:
      class:        Image
      local:        image_id
      onDelete:     CASCADE
      foreignAlias: Thumbnails
```

When you need other parts of code, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "cascade_saves" here for your **databases.yml** file. That should work.

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:               mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase
      username:          ###
      password:          ###
      encoding:          utf8
      attributes:
         cascade_saves: false
```